# How to allow only one session per user?

Tags: php, ajax, session

I am making a platform where you can only access one session per person, to do this, I had to insert in the DB a session id, then, for example:
The user logs in Chrome, at the time of login, in my DB the session id is inserted.
If the same user logs in Firefox, a new session id is inserted, and at the end it compares which was the last id so that only the last person who logged in can have access.
But the problem I have is that, if the user who logged in in Chrome does not make any movement, ie reload the page or click on another, then it stays right there and does not close the session. What I want to do is that when the user logs in on another device or browser, it automatically bounces the first session.
I know that with JS I can call that block of PHP code where I have the validation every certain time, but this would not work 100% because the platform is courses (videos) so if I make the function to run every 5 min example then you can see a course without problem the other person and if I run every 10 seconds I fear that as it sends many requests at once, you have problems with the server. Another question I have is that if I use JS and I set the function with JS then a user who has some knowledge can inspect and delete the JS and then the set code would not be executed or yes?
A more understandable example is what WhatsApp does not let in theory open another session at the same time. Any idea how to solve? Thank you very much.

Comment: There is nothing to solve as it looks like you haven't tried anything yet. Have a look at the help section on how to ask questions on SO. This is NOT a tutorial site.

Comment: Most OnlineBanking sites have a JS counter, starting to run anew after a request.. if you don't do nothing for the next 5 minutes, the session will be closed and the user is redirected to the login.